# Angular 6 Datatable refresh data in table after outside filtering

Tags: html, angular, datatable, angular6, render

i'm trying to render the rows in the table after request.
i can see the the response in the browser and i am pushing the new data to the
ROWS: object, 
but the table is not refreshing the rows in table.

sample code:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { XXXXXXXService } from './NAME.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-NAME',
  templateUrl: './NAME.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./NAME.component.scss']
})
export class XXXXXXXComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  rows = [];

  dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(private XXXXXXXService: XXXXXXXService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.rows.length = 0;

    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 25
    };
    this.class.getRows()
      .subscribe(rows => {
        console.log(rows);
        this.rows = rows;
        // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table -- not working!!!
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      });
  }
  render_rows_filters(filter) {
    this.class.getRowsFiltered(filter).subscribe(
      rows => {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.dtTrigger.next();
      }
    );
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

html

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="table-bordered">
  <!--class="row-border table-bordered hover">-->
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;NAME</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td>{{ row.Name }}</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the npm package that you are using for your `datatable` feature?

Comment: can you not render this table or can you not filter the table after the table is shown?

Comment: @Yong i can filter the table.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel i'm using "angular-datatables": "^6.0.1"

Comment: That library is showing on its documentation that you need to first destroy the table and then trigger the next render. Have you tried that? https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
the thing is that when you use angular with components and services, one component can't declare the DataTable Element to another component running in the same page.
the solution was to **create a outside (Global) service** and pass all the component variables.
then running all the functions in the **Service with the component variables and child's**.

Thank you all... =)

Answer (score 1):

This is best way to refresh data on search .. or dynamic loading

[angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/advanced/rerender)

Answer (score -1):

**datatable refresh**
**Click on button press table grid refresh**

```
$('#Clienttbl').dataTable().fnClearTable();
```